# Send data from Python to .jsp

Tags: python, html, jsp, post, get

i have the following problem:

Im using python in my Raspberry pi 3 to acquire some data. I want to send this data to a .jsp (java server page). I tried using the Requests python library, but whenever i run it, it prints: (500, 'Internal Server error').

Here is the code used in the python script:

```
if AP1snr>=E1liAP1 and AP1snr<=E1lsAP1:
    if (AP2snr>=E1liAP2 and AP2snr<=E1lsAP2):
        if (AP3snr>=E1liAP3 and AP3snr<=E1lsAP3):
            if (AP4snr>=E1liAP4 and AP4snr<=E1lsAP4):
                a=101;
                ban=1;
if ban==1:
    r = 
    requests.post("http://mywebsite.com/localizador.jsp", 
    data={'number': a, 'type': 'issue', 'action': 'show'})
    print(r.status_code, r.reason)
```

Here is the code in my jsp to show the data i sent:

```
<%
        if( request.getAttribute("salon")!=null){
        Localizador localizador=request.getAttribute("Salon");
        %>      
      <tr><td><%=localizador.getNombresalon()%> </td> </tr>
     <%      
      }
   }
%>
```

Finally here is the code of my servlet where i intend to store the data as a variable and make it an attribute in the page:

```
try { 
   String salon = request.getParameter("a");
   localizador localizador= new localizador();

    localizador.setNombresalon(salon);
    request.setAttribute("salon",localizador);


    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(localizadorControlador.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
RequestDispatcher redireccion = 
request.getRequestDispatcher("localizador.jsp");
    redireccion.forward(request, response);
```

Comment: Clearly you know how to use loggers in java. Why don't you look at what the log file actuall says?

Answer (score 0):

the HTTP request will be a POST instead of a GET when the data parameter is provided. Try this

```
import urllib
import urllib2

params = urllib.urlencode({'hello':'there', 'foo': 'bar'})
urllib2.urlopen('http://example.com/test.jsp?+params')
```

Comment: I tried using this code but it does not work, im using requests.post so i dont know why youre saying i need to use post instead of a get? Am I missing something?